# How to simulate/test AJAX exception handler?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I have a PrototypeJS AJAX request like this (third party code):

```
new Ajax.Request(url,
{
    method: 'get',
    onException: function(transport, e)
    {
        //...
    },
    onComplete: function(transport)
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

and want to test the behavior of `onException`. I have control over the server side, so I can change the response. But simply returning a `500` status does not do the trick, it is still handled by `onComplete`.

So what possibilities do I have to trigger the `onException` handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onException` is only fired *when there was an exception while dispatching other callbacks*, see [here](http://prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax), in **Ajax response callbacks**. So I'm not sure there is a way to test it.

EDIT:

I [read (in french, didn't find anything in english)](https://blog.pascal-martin.fr/post/prototype-gestionnaires-evenements-pour-ajax-request.html) that if you make a cross-domain request it fires the vent.

Comment: I was able to make `onComplete` throw an exception, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Defining an `onFailure` callback might be a way to go here, so you don't have to test for success in `onComplete`. The `onComplete` callback is fired regardless of the outcome of the request to the server. If you have a branch that you only want to be followed if there are no errors, put it in `onSuccess` rather than `onComplete`.